# vim color scheme in iterm2 are not the same

Tags: vim, macvim, iterm2

I am using vim in iterm2 and my color schemes looks really weird.. in macvim they are prettier and in my iterm2 thay look horrible.

For example, this is "ir_black":[image: ir_black on iterm2]

And this is "ir_black" on macvim:

[image: ir_black on mvim]

why this is happening and can I fix it?

Answer (score 0):

If you use [the "original" ir_black colorscheme](http://toddwerth.com/2008/04/30/the-last-vim-color-scheme-youll-ever-need/), you'll notice that the `cterm*` values are all color names like `darkgray`. This means that the colorescheme uses whatever default 16 colors you have set up in your terminal emulator.

iTerm's default colors are different from the colorscheme's colors so you get... what you get, which is not what you want.

You have, at least, two *practical* solutions:

- set your terminal emulator's 16 default colors to the ones indicated at line 43 of `ir_black.vim` or
- setup your terminal emulator to pretend that it's `xterm-256color` and use [a 256 colors variant of `ir_black`](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=2777).